# Not able to locate Vagrant Box in mac, using Vagrant 2.2.9

Tags: installation, vagrant, virtualbox, aerospike

I was setting up aerospike, downloaded Vagrant (2.2.9) and virtual box (6.0.2), but I am getting this error.
I have already generated a vagrant file doing a vagrant init.

```
> `The box 'aerospike/centos-6.5' could not be found or could not be
> accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private box on
> HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via 'vagrant
> login'. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded URL and error
> message are shown below:
> 
> URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/aerospike/centos-6.5"] Error: The
> requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant currently seems to have removed centos-6.5 support.
Using the new box vagrant centos-6.10 solved it for me!